# Use sed to find and keep only the lines with 2 alpha characters in them

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file with many lines like these

```
33B87401
33B87402
33B87403
33B8EE44
33B87405
33B87406
33B87407
33B87408
33B87409
33B8740A
33B8740B
33B8740C
33B87D0D
33B8740E
33B8740F
33B87410
33B87411
33B87C1E
33B87CC3
33B87C1C
```

I am looking for a way to keep only the lines that have only 2 alpha characters

output for this exemple would be

```
33B8740A
33B8740B
33B8740C
33B8740E
33B8740F
```

here is another list

```
8765C3E3
8765C3E4
8765C3E5
8765C3E6
8765C3E7
8765C3E8
8765C3E9
8765C3EA
8765C3EB
8765C3EC
8765C3ED
8765C3EE
8765C3EF
8765C3F0
```

Read many examples of sed and awk and non can reproduces this.

Thank you

Comment: `sed 'h;s/[^[:alpha:]]//g;/^..$/! d;//x' <infile`

Comment: Thank you janos and thanks don_crissti , the sed command is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -ne's/[[:alpha:]]//3;t' -e's//&/2p'  <in >out
```

...will `s///`ubstitute away the third occurrence on a line of any character in the `[[:alpha:]]` class. It afterward `t`ests if this substitution was successful, and, if so, branches out of the script.

Because `sed` is instructed `-n`ot to autoprint, input lines with three or more alphabetic characters are at this point effectively deleted from output, and the only input lines remaining for the second `s///`ubstitution statement are those with two or fewer alphabetic characters.

The second substitution uses the empty `//` regex on the left-hand side - which, for `sed`, *(more efficiently)* refers to the most recently compiled `/`*`regexp`*`/` - and so can be read as `s/[[:alpha:]]/...` once again. This one attempts to `s///`ubstitute the second occurrence of an alphabetic character on a line for `&` itself - and as such results in an effective noop and no actual modifications to the line. However, if it can successfully do so, then the line is also `p`rinted to output.

In summary - the first `s///`ubstitution effectively deletes from output all input lines which match three or more alphabetic characters, and the second substitution `p`rints of what remains to output only those which match two alphabetics.

...w/ `grep` ...

```
grep -xE '([0-9]*[[:alpha:]]){2}' <in >out
```

This statement doesn't do exactly as asked. It selects from input only those lines which are comprised of only alphanumerics, and of that subset only those which match no more or fewer than two alphabetics, the second of which must be the last character. This statement will work to produce the example desired output from the example input.

To do as asked, though:

```
grep -xE '([^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]]){2}[^[:alpha:]]*'
```

That statement will select input lines which match no more or fewer than two alphabetic characters which might be found in any position on an input line, and which might be separated by any number of `^` not alphabetic characters.

`grep`'s `-x` switch is used in both cases. Either statement might do without, though, if the `^` head-of-line and `$` tail-of-line anchors were (pre|ap)pended to the regexp respectively. The `-x` switch denotes a *whole-line* match - and so the regexp must describe all matched input lines entirely, from head to tail.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if length s/\d//gr == 2'
```

Which uses:

- `-n` to implicitly wrap a `while ( <> ) {` loop
- `s///r` returns the replaced text, but doesn't modify the original.
- so we remove any digits, then look at the string length
- and print the line if that's 2.

Note: this removes digits from your lines, leaving non digits.  You could use `[^A-Z]` instead.

Or alternatively - if it's clearer:

```
perl -ne 'print if (()=m/([A-Z])/g) == 2'
```

This will work with older `perl` which doesn't support the `r` flag. It uses regex matching to select text, and counts number of array elements (matches). And if that's 2, prints the line.

Comment: the top one doesn't actually look for two alphas - it looks for two not digits.

Comment: Yes. It could be a negated character class instead `[^A-Z]` but the former case is an alternative with the supplied input

Answer (score 1):

i just wrote a simple python script that does exactly you want , i tested it on your input , it works fine.

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   def count_letters(input):
     count=0
     for char in input:
       if char.isalpha():
         count += 1
     return count

  fh=open('test_input','r')
  for line in fh.readlines():
    if count_letters(line) == 2 :
      print line
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines:

`grep '^[0-9]*[A-F][0-9]*[A-F][0-9]*$'`

should do the trick.

This means a pattern that starts at the beginning of the line, has some (perhaps no) digits, a letter, more digits, another letter, and more digits before the end of the line. The anchors are critical, otherwise you'll get all lines with two or more letters.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
awk '{x=$0; gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/, "", x)};length(x) == 2' file
```

This sets each line into a variable `x` followed by replacing all non-alpha characters within `x` with the empty string. If the length of the thus-modified `x` equals `2`, the line in question qualifies

Alternately, with `grep`

```
grep '^[^[:alpha:]]*[:[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*[:[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*$' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -E '^([^[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]){2}[^[:upper:]]*$' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
33B87401
33B87402
33B87403
33B8EE44
33B87405
33B87406
33B87407
33B87408
33B87409
33B8740A
33B8740B
33B8740C
33B87D0D
33B8740E
33B8740F
33B87410
33B87411
33B87C1E
33B87CC3
33B87C1C

% LC_ALL=C grep -E '^([^[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]){2}[^[:upper:]]*$' file.txt
33B8740A
33B8740B
33B8740C
33B8740E
33B8740F
```